# jQuery and javascript - conceptual

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how the browser connects `jQuery` with my custom written javascript file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Let's say my "test.js" file contains:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //some code here
}
```

How does the browser (and text editor) understand that my `test.js` is `jQuery` code?
What would happen if I removed `jQuery` script link and "test.js" remained the same?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp

Comment: @CasBloem be careful when using w3schools web site, see here for more informations http://www.w3fools.com/ ("`For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience. However, it would be a mistake to continue your education without learning from more reputable sources`")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing `jQuery` script file before your test.js and because of that, the browser knows how to handle `$` calls. If you remove `jQuery` script, you will get an error "`$ is undefined`"

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` is the most popular JavaScript library nowadays. It uses CSS selector style syntax to fetch elements in document object model (DOM) into wrapped element set, and then manipulate elements in the wrapped set with jQuery functions to archive different effect. Though the way of using `jQuery` is very easy and intuitive, you should still understand what is happening behind the scene to better master this JavaScript library.

You should read some articles about jQuery before you start. Here are some links:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, if you were to get rid of the link to the `jQuery` library, then any `jQuery` code you are using in your test.js file would give an error.

By linking to the `jQuery` library, you are basically including it into your project just like you would include any other library into a program. This allows you to use the functions provided by the library.

For more information, see the following link: http://learn.jquery.com/